# Python Speed Optimization

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am creating a program (to test a theory), and to get the data I need, I need a program to run as fast as possible.

Here's the problem - I have made it as fast as I could manage and it is still to slow. It is using a very small amount of my computer's RAM and CPU capacity. I am running the program with PyCharm 2017 Community Edition.

The code is below; How would I further optimize or change this to make it run faster?

Main:

```
from functions import *
from graphics import *
import time

Alpha = True

x = timestamp()

while Alpha:
    master = GraphWin(title="Image", width=512, height=512)

    build_image(master)

    getter(master, x)

    x = timestamp()

    time.sleep(3)

    master.close()
```

Module "Functions":

```
from graphics import *
import random
from PIL import ImageGrab


def build_image(window):
    for i in range(513):
        for j in range(513):
            fig = Rectangle(Point(j, i), Point(j + 1, i + 1))
            color = random.randrange(256)
            fig.setFill(color_rgb(color, color, color))
            fig.setOutline(color_rgb(color, color, color))
            fig.draw(window)


def getter(widget, counter):
    x = widget.winfo_rootx()+widget.winfo_x()
    y = widget.winfo_rooty()+widget.winfo_y()
    x1 = x+widget.winfo_width()
    y1 = y+widget.winfo_height()
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save("{}.png".format(str(counter)))


def timestamp():
    timelist = time.gmtime()
    filename = ("Image" + "_" + str(timelist[0]) + "_" + str(timelist[1]) + "_" + str(timelist[2]) + "_" +
                str(timelist[3]) + "_" + str(timelist[4]) + "_" + str(timelist[5]) + "_UTC")
    return filename
```

Note: Module "Graphics" is a module that allows for easy manipulation of Tkinter.

Comment: PyCharm is just going to be using w/e Python interpreter it's configured to use.  It's not going to have much, if any, influence on how your program runs.  This is a very vague question. Use a profiler to figure out what is taking the most time and optimize that.  Depending on your constraints, you might need a faster (non-interpreted) language.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html) I found that you can pass a `bbox` parameter to PIL.ImageGrab.grab. This could save some time. You could also consider using PIL to create your image in the first place instead of taking a screenshot of a window as Austin Hastings suggested.

Comment: @CDspace Rolled back your edit. The question has been solved, please do not change it from current.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or something similar to your post. Since you've accepted an answer, people will see anyway that your problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you @FelixSFD. I was about to roll that back, and FWIW [adding SOLVED to the title is not okay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/242495). The system itself lets us know it's solved if the OP accepted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your slowness is probably from treating the pixels as rectangles in your window.

If all you want to do is generate random images, you can skip the window part. I found this code laying about, after not too much ducking:

```
from PIL import Image
import random

def drawImage():
    testImage = Image.new("RGB", (600,600), (255,255,255))
    pixel = testImage.load()

    for x in range(600):
        for y in range(600):
            red = random.randrange(0,255)
            blue = random.randrange(0,255)
            green = random.randrange(0,255)
            pixel[x,y]=(red,blue,green)
    return testImage

def main():
    finalImage = drawImage()
    finalImage.save("finalImage.jpg")
```

Comment: It works - Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: That could be a LOT faster if you used `putdata` to put all the pixels in at once rather than using that loop. For instance: `testImage.putdata([random.randrange(16777215) for _ in range(360000)])`

Comment: or:  Image.fromarray(np.random.randint(255, size=(600, 600, 3)).astype(np.uint8))  as per my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler to see where your program is fast/slow. Here is a profile wrapper you can use on your functions to see what is taking too long in your program.

```
def line_profiler(view=None, extra_view=None):
import line_profiler

def wrapper(view):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        prof = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
        prof.add_function(view)
        if extra_view:
            [prof.add_function(v) for v in extra_view]
        with prof:
            resp = view(*args, **kwargs)
        prof.print_stats()
        return resp
    return wrapped
if view:
    return wrapper(view)
return wrapper
```

Now how to use it

```
@line_profiler
def simple():
    print("Hello")
    print("World")
```

Now when you run your function, you will get a printout of how long everything takes.

You might need to do `pip install line_profiler`

Answer (score 2):

this may be a bit faster if you use numpy.  loops inside loops will kill your speed.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def drawImage():
    return Image.fromarray(np.random.randint(255, size=(600, 600, 3)).astype(np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do a lot of independent tasks, you could benefit from parallelism. Something like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def build_image(window, start, end, step):
    for i in range(start, end, step):
        for j in range(end):
            fig = Rectangle(Point(j, i), Point(j + 1, i + 1))
            color = random.randrange(256)
            fig.setFill(color_rgb(color, color, color))
            fig.setOutline(color_rgb(color, color, color))
            fig.draw(window)

max_workers = 8
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    for id in range(max_workers):
        executor.submit(build_image, window, id, 513, max_workers)
```